# special charactere generated a arabic word document using php (COM)

Tags: php, ms-word, document, arabic, com+

I would like to generate a arabic word document using php via COM+ interface.

When my document is generated, i open it and i find my arabic words but it's attached to some special characters (something like Chinese words).

How can i have my word document without this characters?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your code.

Comment: i have to wait 8 hours before i show you my code. This is probably the regulation here!! i think it's because i'm new here.I will sent it after this period.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    include_once('configTanfid.php');
    include_once 'DossierTablir.php';



    //if(isset($_GET['nd']) && !empty($_GET['nd'])){
        //$dossier_tablir = new DossierTablir($_GET['nd']);
        $dossier_tablir = new DossierTablir(1);
        $typedoss = $dossier_tablir->__get('typeDossier');
        $numdoss = $dossier_tablir->__get('idDossier');
        $numtab = $dossier_tablir->__get('idDossierTablir');
        $mobalir =  $dossier_tablir->__get('mobalir');
        $mobalar =  $dossier_tablir->__get('nomCompletTablir');
        $mobalarpere = $dossier_tablir->__get('nomPereTablir');
        $numjug = $dossier_tablir->__get('numJugement');
        $datejug = $dossier_tablir->__get('dateJugement');

    //}

    $word = new COM("word.application",NULL ,CP_UTF8) or die("Unable to instantiate Word" );
    //$path=str_replace("\\","/","C:\wamp\www\Tanfid-Application\\contrat1.docx");
    $path="C:\\wamp\\www\\Tanfid-Application\\template.docx";
    if(file_exists ($path)){

        $word->Documents->Open(realpath($path));
        //echo "exist";
    }
    else
        //echo "not exist";

    $current_date = date("m/d/Y");
    $objBookmark1 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("typedoss");
    $objBookmark2 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("numdoss");
    $objBookmark3 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("numtab");
    $objBookmark4 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("mobalir");
    $objBookmark5 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("mobalar");
    $objBookmark6 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("mobalarpere");
    $objBookmark7 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("numjug");
    $objBookmark8 = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("datejug");

    $range1 = $objBookmark1->Range;
    $range2 = $objBookmark2->Range;
    $range3 = $objBookmark3->Range;
    $range4 = $objBookmark4->Range;
    $range5 = $objBookmark5->Range;
    $range6 = $objBookmark6->Range;
    $range7 = $objBookmark7->Range;
    $range8 = $objBookmark8->Range;

    $range1->Text = $typedoss;
    $range2->Text = $numdoss;
    $range3->Text = $numtab;
    $range4->Text = $mobalir;
    $range5->Text = $mobalar;
    $range6->Text = $mobalarpere;
    $range7->Text = $numjug;
    $range8->Text = $datejug;


    $new_file = "C:/Users/Imadeddine/Desktop/Tanfid_Files/Convocation_".$numdoss.".docx";
    $word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($new_file);
    $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);




    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".$numdoss.".docx");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $fsize = filesize($new_file);
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);


    // Send file to browser
    readfile($new_file);
    //unlink($new_file);


    $word->Quit();
    $word->Release();
    $word = null;
    unset($word); 

     ?>
```